# PowerTrack API GNIP - Maxresults

Tags: gnip

Is there a way I can  restrict max result per rule while streaming using GNIP PowerTrack API. Problem is  while streaming if one company has thousands of tweets   and another (second) company has only 10 tweets then first company is exhausting my contract limit of max tweets (that can be streamed). And not getting any tweet stream for second company.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation, there's a rule called "sample" which allows you to specify a percent sample of the rule.  From the [documentation](http://support.gnip.com/apis/powertrack/rules.html):

> Gnip Rule: dog sample:50
>
> Match: 50% of tweets that match the keyword dog